# Is Content-type application/json header needed in response when using getJSON?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm using jQuery function .get to obtain a json structure from a response php page. So I add the "json" parameter (or I just use .getJSON). But I noticed that it doesn't matter whether the remote page returns its json response with content-type header "applicaton/json" or "text/html", because the requesting jquery function will not complain about it and successfully interpret the data received.

So, my question is: is there any point in actually specifying the

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

in the response page, other than being true to the specifications?

Comment: jQuery works on the format of the response, not the headers. So the header should be included to stay true to the standard, but it's not explicitly required for jQuery to function as you need.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Though jQuery only parses the JSON if you use `$.ajax` when the header says it's JSON. At least in my case.